# remove elements which are present in a list more than 2 times

Tags: python-3.x, list, conditional-statements

I want to create a new list where each element can be present at max 2 times.
My code:

```
def valid_element(elements):
    removed = 0
    new_list = []
    for i in elements:
        if i not in new_list:
            new_list.append(i)
    else:
        removed += 1
    print(new_list)
    print('Removed:', removed)
valid_element([1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 8, 8])
```

The output I want:

```
Removed: 2
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 8, 8]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to count unique elements in the list..

```
def valid_element(elements):
    removed = 0
    new_list = []
    for i in elements:
        if i not in new_list:
            new_list.append(i)
        elif i in new_list:
            repeat_count = new_list.count(i)
            if repeat_count < 2:
                new_list.append(i)
            else:    
                removed = i
    print(new_list)
    print('Removed:', removed)
valid_element([1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 8, 8])
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 8, 8]
Removed: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example shows items in sorted order.  If duplicates are next to each other then you can do

```
from itertools import groupby, islice

alist = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 8, 8]
result = [i for k, g in groupby(alist) for i in islice(g, 2)]
```

`result` contains

```
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 8, 8]
```

If you need to know how many were removed you can do

```
num_removed = len(alist) - len(result)
```

If your original list is not in sorted order, and you don't mind reordering then do

```
result = [i for k, g in groupby(sorted(alist)) for i in islice(g, 2)]
```

Finally, here's a version that preserves order

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()
result = [i for i in alist if c.update([i]) or c[i] <= 2]
```